# Vertical alignment on a tags with Flexbox list items

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I have some variable length text in some list boxes, this causes the not match due to the text within a tags not vertical aligning.

I have tried various flexbox options along with the standard vertical align too no avail.

Any ideas how I can center the text within the a tags within Flexbox? I have added the CSS elements from Inspect Element to a Plunker, so not al lparts will be relevant but you'll get the idea.
https://plnkr.co/edit/EAwV0OtXg7Z8mSsHQoho?p=preview

```css
.mobile-buttons > ul.side-list {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-self:center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.938em;
  margin: 0.937em 0 0.937em 0;
}

.mobile-buttons > ul.side-list li {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0.913em;
  line-height: 1.538;
}

.mobile-buttons .blue-bg {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-width: 150px;
  min-height: 17px;
  min-width: 150px;
  font-size: 1em;
  min-height: 17px;
  height: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 17px;
  padding: 27px 2px 27px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.15em;
  top: 1px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn, a.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 17px;
  max-width: 180px;
  min-width: 180px;
  padding: 27px 2px 27px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.15em;
  top: 1px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.blue-bg {
  border: #1D5FD5 1px solid;
  text-shadow: #0a39c2 0 1px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px 0px #8aa2e2, 0px 1px 2px 0 #696b6b;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4089e9 0%,#1d5fd5 100%);
}
```

```html
<section class="mobile-buttons lines-bg clearfix row">
  <ul class="side-list">
    <li><a href="/link1" class="btn blue-bg">The First Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link2" class="btn blue-bg">Long Description on Second Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link3" class="btn blue-bg">Short 3rd Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link4" class="btn blue-bg">Extra description on fourth menu option</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:flex` in `.mobile-buttons .blue-bg`:

```css
.mobile-buttons > ul.side-list {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-self:center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.938em;
  margin: 0.937em 0 0.937em 0;
}

.mobile-buttons > ul.side-list li {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0.913em;
  line-height: 1.538;
}

.mobile-buttons .blue-bg {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-width: 150px;
  min-height: 17px;
  min-width: 150px;
  font-size: 1em;
  min-height: 17px;
  height: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 17px;
  padding: 27px 2px 27px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.15em;
  top: 1px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn, a.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 17px;
  max-width: 180px;
  min-width: 180px;
  padding: 27px 2px 27px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.15em;
  top: 1px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.blue-bg {
  border: #1D5FD5 1px solid;
  text-shadow: #0a39c2 0 1px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px 0px #8aa2e2, 0px 1px 2px 0 #696b6b;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4089e9 0%,#1d5fd5 100%);
}
```

```html
<section class="mobile-buttons lines-bg clearfix row">
    <ul class="side-list">
   <li><a href="/link1" class="btn blue-bg">The First Menu</a></li>
   <li><a href="/link2" class="btn blue-bg">Long Description on Second Menu</a></li>
   <li><a href="/link3" class="btn blue-bg">Short 3rd Menu</a></li>
   <li><a href="/link4" class="btn blue-bg">Extra description on fourth menu option</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Much unwanted code and duplication. Please rewrite as the following. 
Vertical alignment on  tags with Flexbox list items can be done by using  [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

This is achieved by setting

```
.mobile-buttons .blue-bg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.mobile-buttons>ul.side-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0.937em 1.938em 0;
}

.mobile-buttons>ul.side-list li {
  font-size: 0.913em;
  line-height: 1.538;
}

.mobile-buttons .btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-width: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 17px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 27px 2px 27px;
}

.mobile-buttons .blue-bg {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.15em;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: #1D5FD5 1px solid;
  text-shadow: #0a39c2 0 1px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px 0px #8aa2e2, 0px 1px 2px 0 #696b6b;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4089e9 0%, #1d5fd5 100%);
}

.btn,
a.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="mobile-buttons lines-bg clearfix row">
  <ul class="side-list">
    <li><a href="/link1" class="btn blue-bg">The First Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link2" class="btn blue-bg">Long Description on Second Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link3" class="btn blue-bg">Short 3rd Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link4" class="btn blue-bg">Extra description on fourth menu option</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```